# Online Python sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to make a simple app in Python with sockets, but clients only receive the message "Test" sent from the server if they're in the LAN. I tried to run the client (the server is running on my PC) from my laptop and from my PC. In both cases I received the message "Test", but when a friend tries to connect he doesn't receive the message.

Here is my `server.py`:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 7908))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} established")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("Test", "utf-8"))
```

And here is my `client.py`:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("my_public_ip_address", 7908))

print(s.recv(8).decode("utf-8"))
```

I compile `client.py` with pyinstaller before sending it, so that the script can run without Python  being installed on the machine (I don't even have Python on my laptop)

Thanks for taking the time to read and awnsering this :) (Sorry if my english is bad, I'm french)

Comment: "my_public_ip_address" is it PUBLIC IP?

Comment: yeah it is, thanks for anwsering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your friend is outside your LAN: if so you should open/portforward port 7908 on the router to the server.
Open port 7908 on the sever PC firewall.

Your script in this way should work.